# How to remove specific extension file from r directory

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I need to write a code that permanently deletes a specific extension file from my R directory. I need to remove `.log`, `.csv`, and `.xlsx` files but there are some CSV files named `test.csv`, `data.csv` that shouldn't be removed.

Answer (score 1):

```r
all.files <- list.files( path="somewhere", pattern="(\\.csv|\\.xlsx|\\.log)$", full.names=TRUE )
all.files <- all.files[ !basename(all.files) %in% c("test.csv","data.csv") ]

cat( paste0(all.files, "\n") )

cat( "Will delete these files, continue? yN\n" )
ans <- readline()
if( tolower(ans) == "y" ) {
    unlink( all.files )
    cat("done\n")
} else {
    cat("aborted\n")
}
```

Comment: @Sirius-Thanks, the code is working fine but getting this error message `Error: unexpected '}' in "}"`.